# catch the eco-friendly bug

Tags: vocabulaire, formulation-idiomatique

In the French language, I'm searching for a natural way to say,

- Hah, you've caught the eco-friendly bug or what!

My intention in saying this is to say that I was surprised to see someone who always purchases luxury cars having bought an environmentally-friendly car all of a sudden. I have no clue how I should say 'caught the eco-friendly bug.'

Comment: I corrected the answer on the following grounds; let's put the sentence apart:
My intention --  of saying this -- is -- that I was surprised...

Your intention IS NOT that you are surprised, "to be surprised" cannot be an intention; your intention is to EXPRESS or SAY that you are surprised; moreover, the form you are using is not "the intention OF doing something", there is no form associated with your use of the word "intention" and you are using "intention" alone; therefore "of saying this " is wrong;(continued)

Comment: that complement is introduced always by "in". The French is similar: Mon intention en disant cela est de  faire entendre que j'étais surpris de voir etc. My first correction which was essentially the same was correct, I shouldn't lose a point.

Comment: Une curiosité c'est qu'au Québec on a le calque avec attraper/avoir la « piqûre », de l'insecte...

Answer (score 5):

I think there are various ways of conveying the surprise and the term.

> Je vois que tu t'es mis à l'écologie
>
> Je vois que tu as attrapé la fibre écologique
>
> Je vois que tu as attrapé le virus écologique (using Con-gras-tue-les-chiens' answer)

As stated in the other answer, ecologique could be replaced by ecolo, conveying a slightly pejorative or mocking tone (and in Wallonia - Belgium - Ecolo is also the name of the "eco-friendly" political party)

Comment: I think the exact translation for `eco-friedly` would be `écoresponsable`. But yeah, `écolo` is what i would've used too in that case :)

Answer (score 3):

> Qu'est-ce que tu as attrapé le virus écologique !

Or if you want to add a pejorative nuance to the tone of your phrasing:

> Qu'est-ce que tu as attrapé le virus écolo!

Comment: Pourquoi ajouter `qu'est-ce que` au début de la phrase? Cette tournure ne me semble pas correcte

Comment: @Flying_whale Tout comme « Qu'est-ce que tu as grandi ! ». :)

Comment: Well in this specific case it doesn't quite work that well but I must admit I can't put my finger on the grammatical reason. If you really want to use that beginning of sentence, a correct one would be "Qu'est-ce que tu es écolo !"

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens oui, cet exemple précis ne me choque pas, mais les deux phrases de ta réponses, si. Je ne sais pas pourquoi par contre :p

Comment: @Flying_whale I believe the sentence doesn't fly because *Qu'est-ce que* in exclamative sentences is a colloquial *comme* or *que* (*Comme tu as grandi !* / *Que tu as grandi !*) and provides a notion of intensity (= *Tu as beaucoup grandi !*). On the other hand, while *beaucoup attraper* is usable in some contexts (*Qu'est ce que tu as attrapé comme poissons !*), it is hard to assign an intensity to *attraper le virus écologique* which is a true/false statement, just like we would never say *Qu'est-ce que tu as grandi de dix centimètres !*...

Comment: @user168676 > Please don't answer in comments, your propositions seem to be a very good fit for an answer on its own...

Comment: @Laurent S Thanks for the advice, it easier to choose which now on the basis of that example.

Comment: @LaurentS. Hi. What's your take on adding "tout à coup" (as a replacement for the unworkable "attraper" or "se mettre à") to reinforce the idea of his sudden conversion: "*Qu'est-ce que tu es écolo tout à coup !*"?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens Ishare entirely the point of view of Laurent S, except for the detail that the reason is not grammatical but semantic: the concept "attraper" does not allow for degrees of magnitude, intensity, or amplitude, etc; either you've got the virus either you don't; I wonder what could convince  you of that, two juxtaposed ideas maybe: "Tu as attrapé le virus plus que moi.", "Tu as grandi plus que moi.";  why hasn't the first sentence any sense?  It' different for "Qu'est-ce que tu es écolo tout à coup !", that one is acceptable.

Comment: "Qu'est-ce que tu es écolo tout à coup !" sounds definitely better!

Answer (score 0):

Possible supplementary options (more or less jocular according to case)

- Je vois que tu es devenue dingue d'écologie!
- Mais tu es un(e) mordu(e) d'écologie!
- Alors tu es un(e) convaincu(e) de l'écologie?
- Eh bien! Tu ne vois plus que par écologie!
- Serait-tu devenu(e) un(e) fanatique d'écologie?
- On dirait que tu t'es mis(e) au cent pour cent écologique!
- Tu n'as plus que l'écologie dans la tête!

Other forms of a similar style can be found, it's just a matter of taking the time to rake one's mind for them.